# Após alterar icon do Navigation Drawer ele não abre mais

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Eu customizei aquele ícone do menu lateral e coloquei um ícone meu. Segue a imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Problema:
Quando eu clico no Ícone, ele não abre mais aquele menu na lateral.
Segue o código que eu usei para alterar o ícone:

```
toggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.icon_hamburg_min);
drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
```

Seria possível manter esse icone e fazer com que o clique dele abra o menu ?

Comment: A minha resposta respondeu suas dúvidas? Há algo que necessite de melhor explicação?

Answer (score 1):

Isso não faz o que espera que faça.

[ActionBarDrawerToggle#setHomeAsUpIndicator()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html#setHomeAsUpIndicator(int)) serve para indicar qual o Drawable a utilizar quando o *drawer indicator* está desactivado. Ele é mostrado quando [setDrawerIndicatorEnabled()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html#setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(boolean)) é chamado com `false`.
É por isso que quando clica nele o *drawer* não é mostrado, ele está desactivado.

Para alterar o *icon* deve usar o [ActionBar#setHomeAsUpIndicator()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setHomeAsUpIndicator(int)), faça assim:

- Caso esteja a usar a *support appcompat*

  ```
  Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
  setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
  getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.icon_hamburg_min);
  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
  ```
- Caso não esteja

  ```
  Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
  setActionBar(toolbar);
  getActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.icon_hamburg_min);
  getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
  ```